# I have an array inside another array and i want the value of the last element

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an array under another array and I want the value of the last element in Xcode please tell me how can I accomplish the task. The input is like:

```
( ( 1 ), ( 2 ), ( 3 ), ( 4 ), ( 5 ), ( 6 ) )
```

And how can I get `6` from it.

Comment: It is giving me ( 6 ) this output but iwant is only 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last array is:

```
NSArray *inner = [outer lastObject];
```

The last element in the last array is:

```
id obj = [[outer lastObject] lastObject];
```

Note: this code will crash if any of the receivers are empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply find the object using

```
[[array lastObject] objectAtIndex:0];
```

OR

```
[[array lastObject] lastObject];
```

Comment: @iDev But this is what he wants the last object in given array as (6) and then inside this array he can access either first or last element both will be 6 only(it has only one element). So what wrong with this answer.

Comment: @iDev What is wrong with you, firstly I am accessing the last object then the first element in that array. The last object of given data is (6) and in that the first object is 6. Please first see the answer then down vote it